# Custom Escape Sequence In PHP

Tags: php, escaping

I want to convert arrays into storable string formats using a combination of their keys and values bunched together into a serial string delimited by special characters?

But I am also worried that since it is impossible to predict input from a user form, that the input may also contain the characters I have chosen as the delimiters.

Can I implement custom escape sequences to cater for this?

Well the circumstances require that I implement inter-operable, platform independent solutions other than the traditional **serialize** or **json_encode**. Most of the times I don't generate the serial, and only have to consume it from *external* sources.

Comment: What prevents you using from existing methods of saving arrays to storable strings, such as `serialize` or `json_encode`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON is an "inter-operable, platform independent solution". Most languages have a way to convert between JSON and some sort of native object.

XML is another option, you could use PHP's [SimpleXMLElement](https://www.php.net/SimpleXMLElement), but it will be more work to build up the data than just passing an array to `json_encode()`.

Using a standard format like XML or JSON will be the best way to make sure the data is accessible in various languages, since those languages will already have a way to read the format.

Answer (score 5):

User [Serialize()](http://si.php.net/serialize) or [Json_Encode()](http://si.php.net/json_encode)

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [PHP serialize](http://php.net/serialize) functionality, you wouldn't have to worry about escaping.

Answer (score 0):

`addslashes()` is a faster but not as universal a solution as `serialize()`

Answer (score 0):

Another way is with the [WDDX](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.wddx.php) extension.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like you have to use `strip_tags()` function from PHP.